# Видимость блока в зависимости от значения map.getZoom

Tags: javascript, html, leafletjs

На базе библиотеки LeafletJS создал интерактивную карту с отображением меток и точек. Не могу сделать зависимость отображения div'а в зависимости от значения map.getZoom() (значение масштаба карты)
Выполнить это пытаюсь с помощью вставки скрипта в блок  с условием:

```
<div class="headermap">
<script type="text/javascript">
if (map.getZoom() == 2) {
document.write ('<p class="titlemap">Наши проекты</p>')
}
</script>
```

К сожалению никакой реакции я не получил. Надпись как не появлялась так и не появляется.

Прошу помощи. Страница с картой - https://sapfir.niti.ru/testmap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем примере ошибка **(index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined** надо разместить код в testmap/maps/leaf-demo.js, где у Вас определяется карта

Если я правильно понял Вам надо использовать event в LeafletJS

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() == 2) {
      document.write ('<p class="titlemap">Наши проекты</p>')
    }
})
```

Comment: К сожалению,при загрузке надписи не появляется. При увеличении и затем уменьшении карту перебивает "наши проекты" и карта исчезает совсем.

Comment: Вам надо показывать эту надпись при первой загрузке карты или при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба?

Comment: Суть такая. Карта имеет ограничения по масштабу - от 2 до 8. По требованию заказчика, при первичной загрузке карта загружается в масштабе 2, надпись присутствует. При масштабировании (увеличении) надпись должна плавно исчезать (это я уже сам сделаю, главное сделать ее исчезновение), а при отдалении до 2 масштаба - вновь появляться.

Comment: тогда добавьте еще на `map.on('load', function() {` и не используйте `document.write ('<p class="titlemap">Наши проекты</p>')` лучше создайте этот `<p>` изначально и сделайте его невидимым и показывайте/скрывайте когда надо

Comment: как оказалось, ошибка была в количестве "равенств" - конструкция (map.getZoom() === 2) заработала после 3-го "равно". Спасибо!